# Lebesgue measure on $I=[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Can you help me with this :)

$m$ is a Lebesgue measure on $I=[0,1]$, $g\in{L^{1}}(m)$ and 
$\int_{I} gf\, \mathrm{d}m=0$ for all $f\in{C(I)}$. Then I need to prove $g=0$ in $L^1(m)$?

Comment: Hint: $C(I)$ is dense in $L^1(I)$.

Comment: Hi @user117536 could you describe what you have tried so far?

Comment: Hi @JoeTait. Define $h=0$ if $g=0$ and $h=\bar{g}/|g|$ if $g\neq{0}$. Then $h\in{L^{1}}$ and there is a sequence $(f_n)$ in $C(I)$ such that $\Vert{f_n-g}\Vert_1\rightarrow{0}$ and from that, there is a subsequence $(f_{n_{k}})$, $f_{n_{k}}\rightarrow{h}$ a.e. on $I$. Now, I want to use dominant convergence theorem, to obtain $0=\int_{I}|g|dm$, but unsuccessful.

Comment: @user117536 Thank you - I meant to ask for you to add it to the question itself. Just so you know for future, you will often get a better/more tailored response if you add something like that to the question. Anyway, looks like you got some good responses anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose a smooth approximation of unity (also known as [mollifiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier)) $(\phi_\epsilon)_\epsilon$. Choose $x\in I$ and set $g=\phi_\epsilon(x-\cdot)$. Then

$$0=\int_I \phi_\epsilon (x-t) g(t) dt=(\phi_\epsilon*g)(x)\longrightarrow g(x)$$

as $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$ for a.e. $x$. Therefore $g(x)=0$ a.e.

Comment: This is the most succinct proof.

Comment: Hmm... $g$ is zero *everywhere*?

Comment: I'm not sure what $\phi_\epsilon(x-.)$ denotes. Also $g$ is given. How can you set it to $\phi_\epsilon(x-.)$?

Comment: Student, TooOldForMath is being a bit lazy. Define $g^\epsilon = \phi_\epsilon \ast g$. By definition of  $g$, this is zero for each $\epsilon$.  Since $g$ is locally integrable, $g^\epsilon \rightarrow g$ almost everywhere as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$. The proof of this can be found in many textbooks, but you can use Lebesgue's Differentiation Theorem to prove it yourself.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much :)))

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bring this back to basics, you can use properties of outer Lebesgue measure, which is a common building block for defining Lebesgue measure. Using piecewise linear functions and Lebesgue bounded convergence, it's not hard to show that
$$
               \int_{a}^{b}f\,dx = 0,\;\;\; 0 \le a \le b \le 1.
$$
Every open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ can be written as a countable disjoint union of open intervals. So you'll be able to show that the following holds for every open subset $O\subset [a,b]$:
$$
                \int_{O}f\,dx = 0
$$
Building on outer measure: for a general measure subset $E$ of $(a,b)$, there is a sequence of open sets $\{ O_{j}\}_{j=1}^{n}$ such that (a) $E\subseteq O_{j}$ for all $j$, (b) $O_{j'} \subseteq O_{j}$ for all $j \le j'$, and (c) $\bigcap_{j}O_{j}\setminus E$ is a set of Lebesgue measure $0$. Therefore, by the dominated convergence theorem,
$$
          \int_{E}f\,dx = \int_{\bigcap_{j}O_{j}}f\,dx = \lim_{j}\int_{O_{j}}f\,dx =  0.
$$
Finally, for $\epsilon > 0$, Let $E_{\epsilon}=\{ x : f(x) \ge \epsilon \}$ in order to deduce that $mE_{\epsilon}=0$ from $0=\int_{E_{\epsilon}}f\,dx \ge \epsilon\cdot m E_{\epsilon} \ge 0$. This holds for all $\epsilon > 0$. Hence, $f \le 0$ a.e.. Repeat the argument for "$-f$" in order to conclude that $f=0$ a.e..